# PhPMailer - You must provide at least one recipient email address - But sending mails anyway

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I've got a PHPMailer setup which works fine, but when I added BCC it begins to report error. I can't see what exactly causing this issue.

I've got this error report: **You must provide at least one recipient email address.**

The strange thing is, that it's sending the emails correctly to both recipients but never changes to my 'succes.php'-page. It just simply showing the error reporting.

I have tried almost any combination of ADD and Clear, but keep getting somekind of issue. What I'm facing now, does sends the emails, but still reporting error.

My setup is like this:

```
    try {
        // Ens for all
        $mail->Host       = 'localhost'; // SMTP server
        $mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@XXX.dk', 'XXX Mailer');
        $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; 
        $mail->AddAddress("$email");
        $mail->AddBCC("$bcc");
        $mail->Subject = "$subject";
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->Send();
        $mail->ClearBCCs();
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            header('Location: fejl.php');
        } else { 
            header('Location: succes.php');
        }

    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
} // end of if !mail

else { //report the errors
    echo 'TEST ERRORS';
    foreach ($errors as $msg) { //prints each error
        echo " - $msg<br />\n";;
    } // end of foreach
    echo 'End';
} //end of if(empty($errors))
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: AddRecipeient ???

Answer (score 0):

Basic error:

```
    $mail->Send();
    $mail->ClearBCCs();
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
```

You're calling `send()`, removing all the addresses, then calling `send()` again, hence the error.

You've also based your code on an old, obsolete example, so you're probably running an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).